# Position Image and text Responsive

Tags: css

I'm new at CSS and there is so much ways to choose position of elements.

I'm trying to create a render like this in two different cases:

**Case 1 : Enough space on page**

```
[Image] this is the text that I want
```

**Case 2 : Not enough space on page**

```
[Image] this is the text

that I want
```

**What I have right now in these cases: (I'm using display: inline)**

**Case 1 :**

```
[Image] this is the text that I want
```

**Case 2 :**

```
[Image] 

this is the text that I want
```

Thanks in advance for your tips ;)

Comment: PLease post a [mcve]

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text

Comment: or this too https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Why not use floats ?

Answer (score -1):

How about you give this a try?

```
[text class/id] {display:inline; text-align: top}
[image class/id] {float: right}
```

Though this code would only work for making the text wrapped always around the text, which isn't what you want but it is a solution.